# Re-qwrite Oracle SQL using ANSI Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am new to oracle and sql, I would like to know how can I re-write the following sql query using Oracle ANSI join conditions.

```
  SELECT     emp_no,
    (SELECT   emp_title
       FROM   hr_v_employee
       WHERE         organization_code LIKE
           SUBSTR (emp.depart_code, 0, 4) || '00'
             AND emp_position_code =
                (SELECT     MIN (emp_position_code)
                        FROM     hr_v_employee
                                WHERE     organization_code LIKE
                                    SUBSTR (emp.depart_code,
                                   0,
                                   4
                                   )
                 || '00'))
                 || ' '
                 || NVL (employee_deptartment, '-')
                     employee_deptartment
        FROM     employees e, employee_details o
      WHERE     emp.emp_no = o.emp_no(+)
```

Edit 1

This what I have tried, my question is it possible to use join or ANSI standard for sub-query as well?

```
 SELECT     emp_no,
        (SELECT   emp_title
           FROM   hr_v_employee
           WHERE         organization_code LIKE
               SUBSTR (emp.depart_code, 0, 4) || '00'
                 AND emp_position_code =
                    (SELECT     MIN (emp_position_code)
                            FROM     hr_v_employee
                                    WHERE     organization_code LIKE
                                        SUBSTR (emp.depart_code,
                                       0,
                                       4
                                       )
                     || '00'))
                     || ' '
                     || NVL (employee_deptartment, '-')
                         employee_deptartment
            FROM     employees e left outer join employee_details o (emp.emp_no = o.emp_no)
```

Comment: :What have you tried , i think `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will do , read about it , and i am sure you will be able to do it

Comment: @GauravSoni I have included what I have tried, my question is is it possible to use join or ANSI standard for sub-query as well? Thanks

Comment: Try `SUBSTRING (emp.depart_code  0 FOR 4)` and COALESCE() for NVL ,i think this will work for you then

Comment: @GauravSoni That's not correct. SUBSTRING doesn't exist in Oracle, whereas SUBSTR does. And there's no need to replace NVL with COALESCE - both work equally well in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the missing ON keyword for the LEFT OUTER JOIN, your query should be fine:

```
SELECT emp_no,
       (SELECT emp_title
          FROM hr_v_employee
         WHERE organization_code LIKE SUBSTR(emp.depart_code,
                                             0,
                                             4) || '00'
           AND emp_position_code =
               (SELECT MIN(emp_position_code)
                  FROM hr_v_employee
                 WHERE organization_code LIKE SUBSTR(emp.depart_code,
                                                     0,
                                                     4) || '00')) || ' ' ||
       NVL(employee_deptartment,
           '-') employee_deptartment
  FROM employees e
  LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_details o
    ON emp.emp_no = o.emp_no
```

Please note that you have a typo in your column names - it should be called **employee_department** instead of **employee_deptartment**.

Comment: Thanks Frank for pointing that out. I would like to know whether sub queries can be written in a better way than what I have?

Comment: I guess you could get rid of the complete sub-query and use an analytic function instead, but it's difficult to tell without example data. Please edit your question with sample data, expected output and a short explanation what your query is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your help, I wouldn't be in a position to provide data from employees table and other related tables at this point of time. Later I will add some fictitious data though. Appreciated.